# no module called "flask"

Tags: python, vagrant

I'm currently trying to run a file called forum.py in the vagrant directory but it returns an `ImportError: No module named flask`. After I logged out vagrant, when I type `flask --version`, the python version is 3.9.1 and the flaks version is 2.0.2. When I check the python version in vagrant, it returns 2.7.12. When I type `flask-version`, it returns `flask: command not found`. Does it mean the flask is installed to python 3.9 but not 2.7? Moreover, when I make a new directory in IDE for the files, should I choose Python3.9 or Python2.7 as my interpreter?

Comment: Python 2 has been deprecated for some time.

Answer (score 1):

Ideally, together with your file, you have a requirements.txt for you to install the project dependencies on your machine, or better yet, on your virtual environment

Btw, if you are going to use your Global version of Python... Try to use the most current version.

**Try the command:** *python3 forum.py*